# Win32Com.Client error with Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com, python-3.4

I am working with python 3.4 and pywin32-219. And I am trying to use the win32com.client module. I get the following errors. Is there any suggestions that y'all have that will allow me to use win32com.client. All the other win32com.***_*** import just fine. (I am using this in attempt to create documents and charts in MS Excel)

```
import win32com
>>> win32com.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    win32com.client
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
>>> import win32com.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 56, in __init__
    _LoadDicts()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 106, in _LoadDicts
    f = open(os.path.join(win32com.__gen_path__, "dicts.dat"), "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\dicts.dat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 139, in GetGeneratePath
    os.stat(fname)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import gencache
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 662, in <module>
    __init__()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 58, in __init__
    Rebuild()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 649, in Rebuild
    _SaveDicts()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 65, in _SaveDicts
    f = open(os.path.join(GetGeneratePath(), "dicts.dat"), "wb")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 141, in GetGeneratePath
    f = open(fname,"w")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com\\gen_py\\__init__.py'
```

Comment: do you have write access to the `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32com`? The `gen_py` only gets created during `EnsureDispatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that [Python-3.4.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-341/) and [pywin32 Build 219](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/) is correctly installed (feel free to reinstall it). TAKE CARE to 64/32 bit installer, you need the same for the two (and of course the most useable with your OS), it's one of the possible cause of your problem.

Are you administartor of your computer, have you check the write access to C:\Program Files (x86)\python\lib\site-packages\win32com ?(as @Schollii say it) If not, try to become it, it's another error possibility.

You should edit your post to add your windows version (windows 7-8, XP, Vista etc..), the way to become an administrator in the following links => for [Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-do-you-set-yourself-up-as-the-administrator-in/eddfcdc1-d024-446f-ab8c-a5f1ae0ddf43) and [Windows 8](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-User-Account-an-Administrator-in-Windows-8) and for [Windows XP](http://onlineitpro.com/?p=417).

Then after all of this, if the problems isn't solve, try the following (worked for me on windows 7, 64 bit).
Go there: C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\win32 and copy all the .pyd files from here to C:\Python34.

Hope that will help you,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

[Reinstalling](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2014-May/013196.html) the adodbapi solved this issue for me (Python 3.4.1. and Pywin32 build 219 on Win7 x64):

```
py -3 -m pip install adodbapi
```